# Jquery UI Autocomplete for Search Form that Passes Params into Query String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have successfully used Jquery Autocomplete for other forms on my website but this one is giving me trouble.

```
// Controller
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  autocomplete :user, :name, 
  ...
end

// Routes
resources :users do
    get :autocomplete_name, :on => :collection
end

//View  

<% form_tag users_path, method: :get do %>
  <%= autocomplete_field_tag :name, params[:name], autocomplete_name_users_path, :placeholder => "Search by name" %>
     <%= submit_tag "Search", :id => "submit" %>
<% end %>
```

The search form works but the auto complete is not showing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please replace with following in routes.rb file,

```
resources :users do
    get :autocomplete_user_name, :on => :collection
end
```

Please refer [Rails 4 autocomplete](https://github.com/peterwillcn/rails4-autocomplete) for more documentation.